# "The Key to winning" is + -ing or -to?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, infinitives

Is *The key to -ing* followed by *to* or *-ing*?

Example:

> The key to winning is *to practice/practicing*

Comment: They are identical in meaning and are both grammatical.  Personally I think "the key to winning is to practice" sound better, as the replication of the "ing" is jarring to my ears.

Comment: Since ***the key*** is a simple noun form, I think it's more consistent to equate this with *another* noun - *The key to winning is practice* (*not* the infinitive or gerund verb forms).

Comment: ...compare *Necessity is the mother of invention*. Nobody says ***To need...*** or ***Needing** is the mother of invention*, even though it's not obvious to me that either of those are actually "ungrammatical"..

Comment: @TechnCat - on the contrary, the repetition of -ing can add emphasis - the key to winning is practising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both forms are possible.

If you check [Key to success quotes](https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/key-to-success-quotes) then you will find examples, in which a similar phrase **The key to success is...** is used with both `-ing` and `to` forms.

> The key to success **is to focus** our conscious mind on things we desire not things we fear.

Or

> The key to success **is discovering** this innate power and using it daily to deal with whatever
>   challenges come our way.